# std::vector<unsigned char> to QPixmap

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, qpixmap, qbytearray

I can send and get `QPixmap` by `QByteArray`:

```
QPixmap pixmap1;
QByteArray rawPixels;
QBuffer buffer(&rawPixels);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap1.save(&buffer, "PNG");

QPixmap pixmap2;
pixmap2.loadFromData(rawPixels,"PNG");
```

but I have to use `std::vector<unsigned char>` to send my pixmap:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vector;
int size = rawPixels.size();
char* temp = (char*) rawPixels.constData();
vector.resize(size);
for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    vector.push_back(temp[index]);
}
```

Is there an easy way to get a `QPixmap` from a `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: You could try casting vector.data() to a const uchar*. It's not great, but it should work.

Comment: While doing this, save yourself some lines and a loop. `std::vector<unsigned char> v(rawPixels.constData(), rawPixels.constData()+rawPixels.size());` is likely preferred to manually slapping this across a hand-rolled for-loop unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [loadFromData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#loadFromData) with an unsigned char array

```
bool QPixmap::loadFromData ( const uchar * data, uint len, const char * format = 0,
                             Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor )
```

Use [vector.data()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) to get the contiguous underlying data.

Comment: How should the vector look like? {r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a} ? If I want to create one from scratch.